# Getting error on resize img using pillow and python3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Here is my code.

```
from PIL import Image
imgwidth = 800
img = Image.open('img/2.jpeg')
concat = (imgwidth/img.size[0])
height = float(img.size[1])*float(concat)
img = img.resize((imgwidth,height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save('output.jpg')
```

I found this example from a blog. I have run this code and got the bellow error, I am new in python and not understand the actual problem.

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1929, in resize
    return self._new(self.im.resize(size, resample, box))
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

Comment: Try `height = int(...)` rather than `height = float(...)`

Comment: thanks .. I understand the problem.
there was problem on type casting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as `img.resize()` function expect integer value for `height`, so please make sure height should be an integer type.
Update your code with the below code, I hope it should be working for you.

```
from PIL import Image
imgwidth = 800
img = Image.open('img/2.jpeg')
concat = float(imgwidth/float(img.size[0]))
height = int((float(img.size[1])*float(concat)))
img = img.resize((imgwidth,height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save('output.jpg')
```